# COSH distance in R

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a matrix of 3600x513 and i want to determine the distances between the rows to be able to cluster. My problem is I want to use the COSH distance, which is not available in the dist() function of R.

My questions are:

1. is it possible to create my own COSH function and call it on the dist() function and afterwards use the hclust() function?
2. I have another matrix with the COSH distances calculated by MATLAB. can i replace the values of the output of dist() with the distances i calculated before?

Comment: I don't think that `dist` accepts other custom methods. Anyway this question is probably more appropriate on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25468/how-to-input-self-defined-distance-function-in-r look here, this might help.

Comment: 3600x513 is not "big data". It's tiny. A few megabytes. Don't play that buzzword bingo. I remove the tag and the "big data" nonsense from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just add the post from CrossValidated for visibility ([original post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25468/how-to-input-self-defined-distance-function-in-r)):

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(runif(5))
fn <- function(x, y) 1 - cos(x - y)

proxy::dist(mat, method = fn)
```

`proxy` lets you use `dist` with a custom function